# How can I access the information of a vertex, from source code in Apache AGE?

Tags: apache-age

I'm contributing on the development of Apache AGE, so within the source code, if I have the name of a graph as a string, is there a way that I can access any vertex (or edge) information from that graph?

I would like to access the graphid, label and properties of a vertex. Is there any function that I could call to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
select * from ag_label;
```

You will get **graph IDs** under graph column.

```
test=# select * from ag_label;
       name       | graph | id | kind |            relation
------------------+-------+----+------+---------------------------------
 _ag_label_vertex | 16937 |  1 | v    | graph._ag_label_vertex
 _ag_label_edge   | 16937 |  2 | e    | graph._ag_label_edge
 Person           | 16937 |  3 | v    | graph."Person"
 _ag_label_vertex | 24584 |  1 | v    | staff_details._ag_label_vertex
 _ag_label_edge   | 24584 |  2 | e    | staff_details._ag_label_edge
 _ag_label_vertex | 41629 |  1 | v    | visual._ag_label_vertex
 _ag_label_edge   | 41629 |  2 | e    | visual._ag_label_edge
 Movie            | 41629 |  3 | v    | visual."Movie"
 _ag_label_vertex | 49837 |  1 | v    | community_test._ag_label_vertex
 _ag_label_edge   | 49837 |  2 | e    | community_test._ag_label_edge
 node             | 49837 |  4 | v    | community_test.node
 edge             | 49837 |  5 | e    | community_test.edge
(12 rows)
```

To access **vertices** information from that you can run:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graphName', $$
MATCH (v)
RETURN v
$$) as (v agtype);
```

To access **edges** information from that you can run:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('graphName', $$
MATCH (e)
RETURN e
$$) as (e agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cypher query language is used within apache AGE to access edges and vertices information.

The graphid , label and properties of a vertex can be retrieved using the following command:

```
MATCH (v:YourLabel {propertyKey: propertyValue})
RETURN id(v) AS graphid, labels(v) AS label, v
```

in the Apache AGE source code, a library or API can be used to execute Cypher queries on the graph:

```
from age import Graph

# Create a graph object
graph = Graph()

# Cypher query to retrieve vertex information
query = """
MATCH (v:YourLabel {propertyKey: propertyValue})
RETURN id(v) AS graphid, labels(v) AS label, v
"""

# Execute the query
result = graph.execute_query(query)

# Process the result
for record in result:
    print(record)
    # Access graphid, label, and properties here from the record
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Vertex` class from the `apache.age.core.vertex` module to create a vertex object and access its properties.

Here is the example:

```
from apache.age.core.vertex import Vertex

vertex = Vertex(graph_name, vertex_id)
label = vertex.label
properties = vertex.properties
```

This code creates a `Vertex` object with the specified `graph_name` and `vertex_id`. You can then access the label and properties of the vertex using the `label` and `properties` attributes